# target folder is missing after running docker build

Tags: java, docker, maven

I have created this `Dockerfile` which suppose to build the Java project and then run it using the `ENTRYPOINT` script.

```
FROM maven:3.9.3-amazoncorretto-20 AS build
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM amazoncorretto:20-alpine-jdk
COPY ./target ./
COPY entrypoint.sh .
ENTRYPOINT "sh" "entrypoint.sh"
```

for some reason, the command `RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package` is not running or it's not generating the jar file.

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `--from=build` option in the second-stage `COPY`.

```bash
FROM maven:3.9.3-amazoncorretto-20 AS build
...

FROM amazoncorretto:20-alpine-jdk
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target ./
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Each `FROM` line starts the build over from the named base image.  As you have it, you are trying to copy the `target` directory from your host system.  This might work (especially in Java) but it does mean the build from the first stage is completely ignored.  Changing it to `COPY --from=build` and specifying the absolute path in the build stage as the source will get the built jar file from the first stage.

If you're using the current BuildKit Docker build backend, it can figure out that the `build` stage isn't used at all in your current Dockerfile, and it's in fact possible that the `RUN mvn package` step is simply not run.