# how to use gradle build springboot in render.com?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, dockerfile, render.com

1. I have a springboot project that I want to deploy to render.com.
2. So I wrote the following Dockerfile to buidl and run
3. but the first build step is not executed.

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM gradle:jdk17-jammy AS builder
COPY . .
RUN gradle build

#
# Package stage
#
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy as runtime
EXPOSE 8080
ADD build/libs/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

my repository is [here](https://github.com/hezhongfeng/render-docker-spring-boot)

I run `sudo docker build -t spring-boot:1.0 .`

```
[+] Building 0.0s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                              docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 282B                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [runtime 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy                                                                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [runtime 2/2] ADD build/libs/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar                                                                                      0.0s
------
 > [runtime 2/2] ADD build/libs/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar:
------
Dockerfile:13
--------------------
  11 |     FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy as runtime
  12 |     EXPOSE 8080
  13 | >>> ADD build/libs/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
  14 |     ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 8b379d4b-a804-45d6-9c7c-bf2c7815d17f::izxg1a1bnfftz58jx1mjqpd41: "/build/libs/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar": not found
```

Comment: [target folder is missing after running docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76698145/target-folder-is-missing-after-running-docker-build) has the same problem (a missing `COPY --from=builder` option) and I have an answer there with more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM gradle:jdk17-jammy AS build
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle build --no-daemon

LABEL org.name="hezf"
#
# Package stage
#
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-jammy
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```